# Incorrect number of effected rows in db

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have following code in my application, that updates database.

```
MySqlConnection summaryConn = new MySqlConnection(summaryConStr);
MySqlCommand summaryCmd = new MySqlCommand();
summaryCmd.Connection = summaryConn;

int effectedRows = 0;
try
{
    summaryConn.Open();

    foreach (string query in queries)
    {
        try
        {
            if (query.Length == 0)
                continue;
            if (summaryConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                summaryConn.Open();

            summaryCmd.CommandText = query;

            int tempRowCount = -1;

            tempRowCount = summaryCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            effectedRows = tempRowCount > -1 ? effectedRows + tempRowCount : effectedRows;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logExeption(ex);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    logException(exc)
}
```

following is the log of above code:
writeIntoAnalytics: startedOn: 2014-01-16 22:48:17.
6778634 rows updated/inserted/deleted in analytics in 2410.9814453 seconds. 
inserted:0 , updated:905 , deleted:0 . writtingIntoAnalytics completed on: 2014-01-16 23:28:28.
FYI, the target table is indexed, inserting rows are grouped on 8 columns based unique_key index, updating and deleting rows are using auto_increment primary_key.
Here my question is since total rows to update were 905, nothing to insert and delete. Then why effected rows are 6778634? Whereas this behavior is rare, but painful for me.
Can anyone please guide me what I am missing?
Thanks.

Comment: if these queries takes so much time to execute why dont u use stored procedures and sending list of queries to it?

Comment: how you log the counts of updated/inserted/deleted records? can you show the related code?

Comment: @Damith: That is counted through looping over datatable, in each row there is a flag indicating whether the row to insert, update or delete. I have debugged it, and verified, it was working correctly.